# how to write "JUnit test case" android?

Tags: android, junit, testcase

I want to learn `JUnit Tesing` in android. I do google and now I know how to create the JUnit test case. But my problem how to write the logic in that class, I don't know about that.

Suppose I want to write the test case for the custom listview, then how can I achieve? please give me some direction for that.

```
public class CustomlistviewActivityTest extends TestCase {

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}

public void testOnCreateBundle() {       // this is oncreate method
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

public void testOnCreateContextMenuContextMenuViewContextMenuInfo() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");     // this method is for the create the context menu
}

public void testOnContextItemSelectedMenuItem() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");     // this method is for the select the item of the context menu
                //   on select items call the below method named testFunction1()
}

public void testFunction1() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");     // display toast
}

public void testFunction2() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");        // display toast
}

public void testOnItemClick() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");          // display toast
}

}
```

Thanks.